# How to know if anybody change the db_owner in SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I just want to know is that anyway we can check in SQL server if anybody change the db_owner of a database to other login ID

Comment: If its set to the wrong user then fix it and keep an eye on it. Only someone with dba/sysadmin creds could do this. So if you're concerned i suggest you audit permissions and revoke unnecesary privs. Set up some logging and if it happens again.. dust off your DBA-god-ban-hammer and smite them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is recorded in your default trace. This article ( https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/performance/the-default-trace-in-sql-server-the-power-of-performance-and-security-auditing/ )explains in details how to query default trace. It does not tell you who did it and what was the previous owner. But will tell you what time it happened.

Answer (score 1):

Are you running any DMV capture tools like sp_whoisactive, redgate, DPA, etc or had tracing enabled? That will make it easier to see if it catches the SQL that ran making the change.

What I would do now is set up a trigger that will track the aspects of who makes permission changes to your database and log those transactions for future review.

[Example of DDL Trigger.](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/45c57659-fe7a-49d0-bfb0-af42bae83db1/ddl-trigger-to-track-permission-change-in-database?forum=transactsql)

Comment: +1 DDL trigger. Audit. Wait. Watch. Pounce. Smite with the wrath of a vengeful God.